# How to implement this rather complex concept/relation in database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a web application, and I have an issue trying to figure out how to layout the database tables.

I'm not much of a databases guy, but here's the issue:

For example, I want the application to be have two interfaces. First one, you create a new **book**. Second one, you write a new **entry** / **page** in that book (or another).

I thought of having these three tables:
Books, Authors, Entries.

### Books

- book_id
- author_id
- title

### Entries

- id
- author_id
- text
- datetime
- book_id

### Authors

- author_id
- fullname
- username

Of course, tables are not complete. But I'm lost on how to build the relationships between tables well. I want the author to be able to create a new book (this is by creating first entry/page in that book, so *Entries* table has a new record, as well as *Books*.) Or, to add an entry/page to a book.

Also, I'm not sure if Books table should have an `entry_id` column to track/count entries/pages in that book.

I know it might sound vague. But I didn't know what exactly to Google or specifically ask about. If there's a concept in SQL or a good book for a web programmer (I'm good at PHP) that focuses on building web applications with rather complex relations in database, that you can tell me about, would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the relations are complex: an author can create a book and a book can contain entries. Your schema allows the possibility that anybody can create an entry in a book that they didn't create - if you don't want this, then remove the 'author_id' field from the 'entries' table.

But what is your real question?

Comment: Thank you. But, another question: if I want to add a column that counts the `id` of the `entry` with respect to the `book`, how can I do that? Will it mess everything up? For example, 'this is the xth entry in book of id y'.

Comment: @MMag: "This is the xth entry" implies that there is some form of sorting order. Normally sort orders are not stored in a table but rather occur dynamically in a query "select id from entries where book_id = y order by datetime" or "select id from entries order by id". If you want a specific entry (eg the fifth entry) then you would use some form of the 'top' or 'limit' clauses.